# Append JSON values to figcaption

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file with the structure below, which I want to display the make, model, name and price, under each image, but I obviously want the different values.

```
[
    {"instrumentGroup":"Woodwind", "category1":"Instrument", "name":" Bb Clarinet", "price":"£400","quantityAvailable":"10", "description":"ABS resin Buffet B12 student clarinet, clear sound.", "rating":"4", "make":"Buffet", "model":"B12"},
    {"instrumentGroup":"Woodwind", "category1":"Instrument", "name":"Bb Clarinet", "price":"£1700","quantityAvailable":"10", "description":" CX with full round sound and clear tone.", "rating":"5", "make":"Yamaha", "model":"YCL-CX"},
    {"instrumentGroup":"Woodwind", "category1":"Instrument", "name":"Bass Clarinet", "price":"£3500","quantityAvailable":"5", "description":"Student Grenadilla wood bass clarinet with silver plated keywork. Range down to Eb.", "rating":"4", "make":"Buffet", "model":"BC1180"}
]
```

The file is much larger than this but just working with a little for now.

In my html, I have multiple containers as there's more on the page than just this but the structure of the product information is below.

```
<article id="prodList">
            <article id="products">
                <section id="row">
                    <figure class="prodInfo">
                        <!--this makes the whole product area clickable!--><a href="#link">
                            <span class="link"></span>
                        </a>
                        <img src="Images/saxophone.png" alt="instrument" width="100" height="100">

                            <figcaption>

                            </figcaption>
                    </figure>

                    <figure class="prodInfo">
                        <!--this makes the whole product area clickable!--><a href="#link">
                            <span class="link"></span>
                        </a>
                        <img src="Images/saxophone.png" alt="instrument" width="100" height="100">

                            <figcaption>

                            </figcaption>
                    </figure>

                </section>  
            </article>  
</article>
```

I want to display the information within the figcaption, with make/model on one line, name on the next then price on the next. My .js file below is printing out the last value in the JSON file under every image, but I can't work out how to print each value as it is going through and then stop when it reaches the 18th value.

```
$.getJSON("products.json", function(result){

        $.each(result, function(key, val){
            $('figcaption').html(val.make + " " + val.model + "<br/>" + val.name + "<br/>" + val.price);
        });
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Eventually I will use a paginator to display the next 18 values on the next page, but once the first is working I believe this should be easier. 
The main issue is how to separate them so it prints one in each div.

Thanks.

Comment: .html() clears your previous value so try using .append() method like this: $('figcaption').append(val.make + " " + val.model + "<br/>" + val.name + "<br/>" + val.price);
        });

Comment: That just prints them all in a list under one of them, I need to find a way to move onto the next figcaption each time it loops

Comment: if you have sth that identies each instrument in your json data (name perhaps?), you could of course use it to find the relevant figcaption. Then again how you identify the right figcaption, that is which figcaption belongst to a certain kind of instrument? -I couldn't see any id or descriptive attributes for  figcaption.

Comment: Yeah that was my last resort, I just wasn't sure if there was a cleaner way to do it!

Comment: For example, if the descriptive data was img tag's alt attribute value (instrument), you could find all the json data that has 'category1' value 'Instrument' and append those or sth similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.getJSON("products.json", function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(key, val){
        if (key < 18) {
            $("figcaption").eq(key).html(val.make + " " 
            + val.model + "<br/>" + val.name + "<br/>" + val.price);
        }
    });        
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6ftjLLjv/

Comment: Ah this is perfect and along the same lines as what I'd just worked out myself using the nth-of-type! Thank you!